# Array to string conversion, comparing arrays

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I need to compare these two arrays `$answers_selected` and `$correct_answer` but the first one is showing error

> Array to string conversion

please can anyone help me I am new on laravel..? this is the code:

```
$answers_selected = $request->except('_token', 'test_id');
foreach($questions as $question){

    $answers = Answer::where('question_id', $question->id)

                    ->where('deleted',0)
                    ->get()->toArray();

    foreach($question->answers as $answer){

        $correct_answer = Answer::where('id', $answer->id) 
                                ->where('correct', 1)
                                ->where('deleted',0)
                                ->get()->toArray();

        if(count($correct_answer) == 1){
            $answer_result = 1;
        }
        else{
            $answer_result = 0;
        }

    } 
    $result = array_diff($answers_select, $correct_answer);

    return view('website.questions.partials.multiplechoice.prov')
                ->with(['request' =>  $result]);

    }
```

Comment: Use debugger or dump out the arrays to see what the values are: `dd($answers, $correct_answer)`.  Not sure this is going to work anyways since you appear to be trying to compare multidimensional arrays.

Comment: check the [diff](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-diff) method

Comment: I think there is a problem in your logic !! why you need to reload correct answers `$answers` are already correct because you did `->where('correct', 1)` in the first query !! and there is some messing `}` ...

Comment: where are the questions from?

Comment: I think this code snippet contains so broken part the makes the question not clear. You said you are comparing $selected_answer, and then we see `array_diff($answers, $correct_answer);` also there is no use of `answers_selected` in the code.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve: to get all questions that have a matching answer ids, or to simply check if the answer given matches any question?

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me, i edited somethings but still it is not working, I have a test with multiple questions with checkbox, so in db I saved correct as 1 and incorrect 0, so when I am taking the test I want to compare what user is clicking with my correct answers in db, if in db I have a question with 4 answers and 2 are correct, when the user clicks one correct one not, so he does not click both correct I want to appear as all question incorrect. hope you can understand what I am trying to do. thanks

Comment: Can you update you question with the entire method in your controller to help us see the problem !!